Inconsistent results between Terminal Wave Port and Terminal Lumped Port using Ansys HFSS…
I am trying to simulate a 100 ohm differential impedance FCC flat cable (Molex) but I can't find consistent results when using the Lumped or Wave terminal ports.
My aim is to simulate 24 inches long cable. But as it is very processor demanding, I want to simulate a portion of the cable (here 5 cm) and virtualy increase the lenght of the cable by de-embeding it.
Problem is I cannot use lumped ports because using lumped port do not give the possibility to use de-embeding for extend lenght of cable. So I need to to use wave ports.
The structure of the cable  is following and I am trying to simulate common signal :


When using terminal Lumped port, I got 50 ohm result for a common signal with two GND around it (GND/ SIG / GND ) :

Unfortunatly, when using terminal wave port, I got 38 ohms instead of 50 :



I have tried to modify a little the port geometry so that there is 3 digit scale for the E-field on the wave port, and a better e-filed vector distribution but I still get 38 ohm instead of 50 ohm...

I think the geometry for my port is OK because if I increase it like this, I got oscillation on the TDR response, but still 38 ohms:

Do someone have any idea to get better result using wave port ?
Thanks you very much !
